# QueryInterface call on the COM component failed TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY (calling VB6 from VS2013)

Tags: asp.net, dll, vb6-migration

I already added the reference and registered the dll file on syswow64 (because it is a 32bit dll). I also set the debug platform to x86, and yes, i did enable 32 bits applications on the AppPool of the iis.

The error is produced on this line:

```
Dim calc As New WBCalculoProd
```

WBCalculoProd is the vb6 dll, and this is the error message:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'WinBlindCalculoProd.WBCalculoProd'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{B4888181-1DA3-4E7F-B4E4-3D5A6C32CCE2}' failed due to the
>   following error: Error al cargar la biblioteca de tipo/DLL. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

I am using visual studio 2013, vb.net and .NET framework 4.5

What am i doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be a missing dependency. 

Any chance you can migrate this VB6 DLL to VB.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [COM Exception - TYPE\_E\_CANTLOADLIBRARY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705613/com-exception-type-e-cantloadlibrary)

Comment: R. J. Dunnill I would have to use visual studio 2008 for what i read. For now thats not an option.

Comment: The VBUW is bundled with VS 2002-2008, but once generated, the migrated code is compatible with later versions of Visual Studio, including 2013.

Comment: Thanks R.J. Dunnill, it was a missing dependency! I had to check the code of the dll in mention. Again, thank you.